# Openfire server is not starting after upgrading the MAC wiht Maverics OS

Tags: openfire, osx-mavericks

I am facing problem to start the Openfire Server in Mac with Maverics OS, Before upgrading the Mac i successfully done things but now i am unable to start the Sever. Please help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i find out the problem.

The following are the reasons.

1. 10.9(Maverics OS) installs a new java version v7 64bit, but the client needs older version v6 32 bit.
2. After updating to OS X "Mavericks," (re)install this Java version
   from Apple Support:  Java for OS X 2013-005 delivers improved
   security, reliability, and compatibility by updating Java SE 6 to
   1.6.0_65. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Now openfire working as usual.